# How to resolve error - package com.squareup.okhttp3 doesn't exist?

Tags: java, json, maven, netbeans, okhttp

I am trying to convert JSON to JAVA object with the use of GSON in MAVEN, I am following a youtube video for guidance - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqgghm9pWe0 , however theres an error which occurs when in the Main Class the error is - package com.squareup.okhttp3 doesn't  exist. The code is below:

**Java**

```
package com.codebeasty.json;
import com.squareup.okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public class Main {

    private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    }

}
```

I even put in the dependency in pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
 <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
 <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
 <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I dont understand why it doesn't recognize the com.squareup. Is there something extra I may need to download? I have downloaded the JAR from this website - http://square.github.io/okhttp/ and also tried building the project with dependencies. Please help :(

Comment: I hope you get this error in your IDE (netbeans). Did you try to compile the code using the command line? You can navigate to your project. Do "mvn clean install". Seems like auto install dependencies functionality is not enabled.
.

Answer (score 0):

[Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp) has latest version 3.4.1. Trying changing version in pom or install downloaded in your local using

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/okhttp-3.4.2.jar -DgroupId=com.squareup.okhttp3 -DartifactId=okhttp -Dversion=3.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will downloading the later version have a effect?

Comment: latter version 3.4.1 ? donot know please check backwork compatibity.

Comment: Would I have to to install anything to make the okhttp work? and I have version 3.4.2

Comment: If you are using public repo [Maven repo] (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp), anything avaiable here will automatically installed in your local repo. But if you use something that is not in your remote repo you need to download that jar and then run maven install it in local repo which creates a folder in ~/.m2/repository/

Comment: sorry for typo using mobile